# Multiple objects inside of the existing object

Tags: javascript

Currently I have this type of array accessible by `companyServiceRateOffsets[n]`:

```
var companyServiceRateOffsets = {
    3: { timeworked: 12.25, billabletime: 15.00 },
    15: { timeworked: 14.25, billabletime: 25.00 },
    24: { timeworked: 17.25, billabletime: 35.00 },
}
```

Could I possibly extend this array by having multiple objects inside of the existing? Like:

```
var companyServiceRateOffsets = {
    3: {
         { timeworked: 12.25, billabletime: 15.00 },
         { timeworked: 13.25, billabletime: 16.00 },
    },
    15: {
         { timeworked: 14.25, billabletime: 25.00 },
         { timeworked: 15.25, billabletime: 26.00 },
    },
    24: {
         { timeworked: 17.25, billabletime: 35.00 },
         { timeworked: 18.25, billabletime: 36.00 },
    },
}
```

The above example doesn't work, but ideally it should. Please help.

Comment: you can make them as arrays `3: [
         { timeworked: 12.25, billabletime: 15.00 },
         { timeworked: 13.25, billabletime: 16.00 },
    ]`

Comment: *Currently I have this type of array*. No, it's not an array, it's an object. I'd go back and re-read some basic tutorials on JS data structures.

Comment: @AlexG On the contrary, there are about a thousand. You could do worse that start off with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures. The comment was meant constructively, I'm sorry you didn't take it that way. In general, for basic knowledge, such as "how do I represent a list of things in JS?", you're better off reading tutorials and walk-throughs. It's more effective, and also such questions will often be down-voted. SO tends to work better for programming questions of the "why doesn't this work?" variety.

Comment: @torazaburo: there is no need to waste everyone's time by telling people what to read, there are no answers to my question in those tutorials. That's why I come here. Did you see the accepted answer? Please avoid any further conversations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an array

```
var companyServiceRateOffsets = {
    3: [
         { timeworked: 12.25, billabletime: 15.00 },
         { timeworked: 13.25, billabletime: 16.00 }
    ],
    15: [
         { timeworked: 14.25, billabletime: 25.00 },
         { timeworked: 15.25, billabletime: 26.00 }
    ],
    24: [
         { timeworked: 17.25, billabletime: 35.00 },
         { timeworked: 18.25, billabletime: 36.00 }
    ]
};
```